# Counter example needed for the following in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Let {$g_n:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$} be a sequence of functions that converges point-wise to $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $g_n$ converges uniformly on $[k-1, k]$, give an example of {$g_n$} that does not converge uniformly to $g$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Previously I have proven that if

"Suppose $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $g_n$ converges uniformly on $[k-1, k]$ and that the domain of {$g_n$} is change to $[0, M],\ M\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ instead of $[0,\infty)$",

Then this means {$g_n$} converges uniformly to $g$ on $[0, M]$.

But $M$ can be make arbitrarily large, hence I can't think of an example(counter-example) here.

Any help or insights to my problem is deeply appreciated.

Comment: How about $g_n = \chi_{[n,n+1}?$

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the notation of the right hand side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

A quick counterexample would be
$$g_n:=\chi_{(n,n+1]},$$
where $\chi$ denotes the *indicatrix function* (i.e. the function whose values are $1$ for $x\in(n,n+1]$ and $0$ otherwise). As $g_n$ is $0$ on $[k-1,k]$ if $n\geq k$ it is clear that $(g_n)_n$ converges uniformly to the $0$ function on $[k-1,k]$ (notice that this implies also that $(g_n)_n$ converges pointwise to $0$). However this convergence cannot be uniformly on $[0,+\infty)$ because $\sup_{x\geq0}|g_n(x)|=1$ for every $n$.